# Combinatorics with gaps bigger than one

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many 20-letter strings of letters (the 26 in the alphabet) contain exactly four A's with the added property that there must be a gap of at least 2 intervening letters separating the A's?
My way of thinking is I think flawed.
You have 8 groups of 2 non A's so 9 gaps.
so 9C4 *25^16 to place the A's in gaps and order the non A's
Then if you place them in what I call the odd gaps, starting after the 1st non A. There are 8 gaps
so 8C4*25^16.
But I think I am missing the mix of odd and even gaps, and I am not sure how to account for those.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are ${14\choose 4}$ strings of four $\alpha$'s and ten $\beta$'s. Replace the first three $\alpha$'s by $A\beta\beta$ and the last simply by $A$. This shows that there are $14\choose 4$ ways to have a $20$ symbol string over $\{A,\beta\}$ with exactly four $A$'s and gaps $\ge 2$ between consecutive $A$'s.
After that, there are $25^{16}$ ways to replace the $16$ $\beta$'s with letters from $\{B,\ldots, Z\}$. In total, we obtain
$$ 25^{16}{14\choose 4}.$$

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks so much!!